# How to find out if dgrid has finished with loading data from store

Tags: dojo, dgrid

does anybody know how can I find out if dgrid has finished loading data from the store?

I've been trying to find a way to do this in dgrid's OnDemandList.js but unfortunately it's above my current knowledge of dojo.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this solution some time ago, for `dgrid v0.3.0`, but looking at sources it seems nothing changed so far, so I will try to adapt my solution for v0.3.3.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/FkANy/

The problem is that `dgrid/_StoreMixin::_trackError` does not define *success* callback when returning `Deferred::when`, therefore you need to override that method, define *success* callback and fire *refresh* event there.

`_RefreshMixin` module:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/_base/Deferred", "dojo/on"], function(declare, lang, Deferred, listen) {

    function emitError(err){
        if(typeof err !== "object"){
            err = new Error(err);
        }
        err.grid = this;

        if(listen.emit(this.domNode, "dgrid-error", {
                grid: this,
                error: err,
                cancelable: true,
                bubbles: true })){
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    var _RefreshMixin = declare(null, {

        _trackError: function(func){
            var result;

            if(typeof func == "string"){ func = lang.hitch(this, func); }

            try{
                result = func();
            }catch(err){
                emitError.call(this, err);
            }
            return Deferred.when(
                result, 
                // success callback instead of `null` in _StoreMixin:
                lang.hitch(this, function() {
                    // fire 'refresh' event
                    listen.emit(this.domNode, "refresh", {
                        cancelable: true,
                        bubbles: true
                    });
                }),
                lang.hitch(this, emitError)
            );
        }
    });

    return _RefreshMixin;

});
```

Declare your own grid class and instantiate it:

```
var MyGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, _RefreshMixin]);
var grid = new MyGrid({ /* params here*/ });
```

Now you can listen to *refresh* event:

```
grid.on("refresh", function(event) {
    // your handler
});
```

Comment: Thatnks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Very nice modular solution. Gotta say, you seem to be the only one around here willing to talk about dgrid :)

Comment: Well, this one took me a while about a year ago, so it would be a pity not to share ;)

Answer (score 3):

On **dgrid 0.3.5** you can listen to `dgrid-refresh-complete` event, emitted when results finish rendering.

OnDemandList/Grid wiki page: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid